# getJSON method doesn't work with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, getjson

Im trying to build a mobile application from my webapp with PhoneGap. Everything works fine on desktop browser, but when I move files to PhoneGap the getJSON method doesn't seem to work. What could be the reason?

This is the code I use:

```
$('#employeeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getEmployeeList();
});

setInterval ( "getEmployeeList()", 10000 );
var vanhadata = "";

 function getEmployeeList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php?autonumero=' + autonumero, function(data) {
       if(JSON.stringify(data) != JSON.stringify(vanhadata)){ 
            $('#employeeList li').remove();
            employees = data.key;
            $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
                $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="keikka.html?id=' + employee.IND + '">' +
                    '<h4>' + employee.OSO + '</h4>' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + employee.TILA + '.png"/>' +
                    '<p>' + employee.AIKA + '</p>' +'</a></li>');
        });
            $('#employeeList').listview('refresh');

            if(vanhadata != "")
               alert("Uusia keikkoja!");       
            vanhadata = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Because it is cross-domain request I have also tried to use callback=? but that doesn't work either. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for this. Phonegap has a white-list feature, so if you are referencing external hosts, you will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. For example if I want to connect to google need to add "google.com" to externalHosts list